# How to make a copy constructor when inherited private values?

Tags: java, inheritance, copy-constructor

I need to make a unit converter for a task at the uni.
Therefor we had given this code:

```
public abstract class SIUnit {
    enum EUnitType {
        DISTANCE,
        MASS,
        TIME
    };

    private double value;

    private EUnitType unitType;

    public abstract void setDerivedValue(EUnitType newType, double newValue);

    public abstract double getDerivedValue();
}
```

So the values where given as private. Now we needed to make some construtors for SIUnit.
The second task was to create some classes with spezified unittypes and a constructor and a copy  constructer
My Question is how to make the copy constructor if all my params are private?

Comment: Maybe call setDerivedValue?

Comment: this is for unit conversion

Comment: You can work with class fields within the class, so I do not see the problem? Can you explain more?

Comment: Are you just trying to implement the constructor for SIUnit? If so, mentioning the creation of the subclasses doesn't add anything.

Comment: A class itself can access all of its own values, regardless of on which instance they are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can access the private parameters, since the copy constructor is located within the same class. So for your copy constructors, it would look something like this:

```
public SIUnit(SIUnit inUnit){
    value = inUnit.value;
    unitType = inUnit.unitType;
    //Same thing for the rest of the instance variables
}
```

Comment: In Java, there is nothing like "copy constructor", I mean it's not anyhow special. Accessing private fields is possible not only from constructors - who would be able to use the fields if not the class on its own?

Comment: That's true - I didn't mean the copy constructor specifically, but just within the class. I think the original question was asked because the new instance isn't just accessing its own values, but also the values located within a separate instance. I'll update my answer to make that a little clearer.